# Fitnesse test against empty string result

Tags: fitnesse

I'm using Fitnesse SliM and I want to check if the result of a fixture is the empty string. Leaving the result field in Fitnesse empty just results in an ignored test which is obviously not what I want. I could solve this by extending the fixture code, but I wonder if this can be handled within Fitnesse itself.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that Slim implies an empty string as an ignore, at least for the [QueryTable](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SliM.QueryTable) fixture: *A cell that is left blank in the table will be filled in from the result and counted as ignored*.

Even though this is not considered a good solution, if you really have to you could use a regular expression to test on an empty string by matching on

```
=~/^$/
```

Another option is using the *null fixture* driver, as seen in http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteSlimTests.SlimSymbolsCanBeBlankOrNull

Answer (score 5):

passing the word 'blank' simulates a empty string.

like:

|Check|That the returned string is | blank |

Comment: I know the 'blank' keyword works with fitSharp (the .NET version) but AFAIK it's not supported for SLIM.

Answer (score 4):

In this case - when you need to check with SLIM usage, whether the result is an empty string, you can use markup variable. Just define it somewhere on your page with test, like:

!define blank {}

And then call it anywhere you want:

|check|SomeFixtureName|${blank}|

Comment: This works for SLIM, thanks for the answer!  For non-SLIM it seems 'blank' should be the preferred option as @ryber's answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It still ignores the test.